# asp.net mvc 2 and mef strange exception at iis at start

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, iis, mef

I am using asp.net mvc2 and mef to create pluggable architecture from [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hammett/archive/2009/04/23/mef-and-asp-net-mvc-sample.aspx) 
When i deploy my project on real iis (7.0, windows 2008 server) i always got an mef exception at first request from client browser:

```
global.asax
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value() in c:\dev\mef\MEF_SVN\tags\Preview6\src\ComponentModel\System\Lazy.cs:line 61
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ReflectionModelServices.LazyExportDefinition.get_Metadata() in c:\dev\mef\MEF_SVN\tags\Preview6\src\ComponentModel\System\ComponentModel\Composition\ReflectionModel\ReflectionModelServices.cs:line 345
```

Cant understand how to fix it. Thanks for all responses and ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a bit more code it's quite hard to debug. I would hazard a guess and say that you are using an early build of MEF (for the .NET v2.0/3.5 platform). I've done some previous work with ASP.NET MVC and MEF:

1. [Modular ASP.NET MVC using the Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF), Part One](http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=104)
2. [Modular ASP.NET MVC using the Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF), Part Two](http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=130)
3. [Modular ASP.NET MVC using the Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF), Part Three](http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=159)

and

1. [MVC3 and MEF](http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=259)

It's worth investigating the differences between these different implementations, and its also worth making sure you are actually using a version of MEF that is more or less feature complete (the one attached to my project above is an example).